# Google maps API Searching postcodes in a specific country

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-geocoder

I'm trying to set a Post Code in order to get Lat and Long Coordinates and place a marker on it. Until now, everything is fine.

The problem comes when I give a postcode input and it ends up making a marker somewhere in another part of the world.

Ex: I type 2975-435 and I get :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2975-435&key=YOURKEY

```
"formatted_address" : "Balbey Mahallesi, 435. Sk., 07040 Muratpaşa/Antalya, Turquia",
```

And I want to make this postcode only be searched in Portugal.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2975-435+PT
This way I get:

```
"formatted_address" : "2975 Q.ta do Conde, Portugal",
```

Exactly what I wanted.

The problem is, how do I make this in JS code?
Here is the code I have till now

```
function codeAddress () {
    var lat = '';
    var lng = '';
    var address = document.getElementById("cp").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address},

    function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            //Just to keep it stored
            positionArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
            //Make the marker
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                map:map
            });

        }else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To restrict a result to certain country you can apply a component filtering:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ComponentFiltering

So, your JavaScript code will be

```
function codeAddress () {
    var lat = '';
    var lng = '';
    var address = document.getElementById("cp").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 
        'address': address,
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: 'PT'
        }
    },

    function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            //Just to keep it stored
            positionArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
            //Make the marker
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                map:map
            });

        }else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

You can see a component filtering in action using the Geocoder tool:

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D2975-435%26options%3Dtrue%26in_country%3DPT%26nfw%3D1

Hope it helps!